# Какая разница между .offset и .inset в SnapKit?

Tags: ios

В SnapKit .offset и .inset выполняют внешне похожие действие. В каких случаях правильно будет использовать .offset(), а в каких .inset()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вкратце - для верхней и левой границы offset и inset дают одинаковый результат, а для правой и нижней - противоположный. Это значит например, что если если левую границу вью 1 прикрепить к правой границе вью 2, то положительный offset сдвинет вью 2 вправо, а inset влево, ну и если одно вью внутри другого, то результат тоже будет разный.

В целом эти методы взаимозаменяемы, если держать в уме указанные нюансы и корректировать значения

Смотрим пример из [документации](http://snapkit.io/docs/)

```
let box = UIView()
superview.addSubview(box)

box.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    make.top.equalTo(superview).offset(20)
    make.left.equalTo(superview).offset(20)
    make.bottom.equalTo(superview).offset(-20)
    make.right.equalTo(superview).offset(-20)
}
```

То же самое что

```
box.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    make.edges.equalTo(superview).inset(UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20))
}
```

Вот еще пример для наглядности

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let greenBox = UIView()
        self.view.addSubview(greenBox)
        greenBox.backgroundColor = .green
        greenBox.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
           make.width.height.equalTo(50)
           make.center.equalTo(self.view)
        }

        // offset to green

        let redBox = UIView()
        self.view.addSubview(redBox)
        redBox.backgroundColor = .red
        redBox.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.height.equalTo(50)
            make.leading.equalTo(greenBox.snp.trailing).offset(20)
            make.top.equalTo(greenBox.snp.bottom)
        }

        // inset to green

        let blueBox = UIView()
        self.view.addSubview(blueBox)
        blueBox.backgroundColor = .blue
        blueBox.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.height.equalTo(50)
            make.leading.equalTo(greenBox.snp.trailing).inset(20)
            make.top.equalTo(redBox.snp.bottom)
        }

        // offset black inside yellow

        let yellowBox = UIView()
        self.view.addSubview(yellowBox)
        yellowBox.backgroundColor = .yellow
        yellowBox.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.height.equalTo(50)
            make.leading.equalTo(greenBox.snp.trailing)
            make.top.equalTo(blueBox.snp.bottom)
        }

        let blackBox = UIView()
        yellowBox.addSubview(blackBox)
        blackBox.backgroundColor = .black
        blackBox.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalTo(yellowBox).offset(10)
        }

        // inset purple inside gray

        let grayBox = UIView()
        self.view.addSubview(grayBox)
        grayBox.backgroundColor = .gray
        grayBox.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.height.equalTo(50)
            make.leading.equalTo(greenBox.snp.trailing)
            make.top.equalTo(yellowBox.snp.bottom)
        }

        let purpleBox = UIView()
        grayBox.addSubview(purpleBox)
        purpleBox.backgroundColor = .purple
        purpleBox.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalTo(grayBox).inset(10)
        }

    }

}
```

[image: boxes]

Comment: меня смущает их "взаимозаменяемость". почему бы тогда не избавиться от, напрмер, от offset (чтобы не связываться с отрицательными значениями) и пользоваться только inset? но почему-то есть и то и то ... в чем смысл? должен же быть смысл )

Comment: @xhr потому что в разных ситуациях удобнее использовать то одно, то другое, главное уяснить разницу

Comment: а можно примеры, когда явно удобнее одно, а когда явно другое?

Comment: @xhr в примере с `inset purple inside gray` явно удобнее inset, а offset удобнее там где всегда нужно смещение в указанном направлении

Comment: ну, наверное вы правы ) я думал, есть какой-то более глубокий смысл ))))

Comment: @xhr все проще чем кажется